# How to post Image from xamrine to webapi in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, steam-web-api

Here is my webapi code that is correct i check that i post the
image using postman..how to send image to webapi image save is already work .but i need how to post image from xamrine to webapi request.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostData([System.Web.Http.FromBody] string Name,HttpPostedFileBase Picture)
{
    ResponseModel response = new ResponseModel();
    try
    {
        //using (AndroidApiPostEntities db = new AndroidApiPostEntities())
        //{
            Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic> dic = new Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>();
            string img = "";
            img = ImageUpload(Picture);
            PostPicture p = new PostPicture();
            p.Name = Name;
            p.Picture = img;
            //db.PostPictures.Add(p);
            //db.SaveChanges();
            response.error = false;
            response.message = "data added successfully.";

            dic.Add("Id", 0);
            dic.Add("Name", p.Name);
            dic.Add("Picture", p.Picture);
            response.data = dic;

            return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        //}
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response.error = true;
        response.message = "inner exp: " + ex.InnerException.Message + " /second/: " + Convert.ToString(ex.InnerException);
        return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}

private string ImageUpload(HttpPostedFileBase img)
{
    string fileName;
    string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(img.FileName);
    Random rnd = new Random();

    fileName = "b" + rnd.Next(1000).ToString("000") + extension; //Create a new Name for the file due to security reasons.

    // string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ImageName;

    //var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "images", fileName);

    //string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ImageName;
    string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("/images/" + fileName);
    //string physicalPath = "~/images/" + fileName;

    // save image in folder
    img.SaveAs(physicalPath);
    return fileName;
}
```

Now here is my xamrine button click code how to post image or how to convert image to post it also hit the api here is code but i face image error i face null picture on webapi

```
private async void btnsubmit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string picc = MyImage.Source.ToString();


         PostUserAsync(txtName.Text, "");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.InnerException.ToString(), "OK");
    }
}

static MediaFile files;

public async void PostUserAsync(string name, string pic)
{
    string Host = "http://dxxx5.expxxxxxxxion.com/Home/PostData";
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var ss=MyImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
    {
       var stream = files.GetStream();
        return stream;
    });



    byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(files.Path);
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    var fileData = webClient.Encoding.GetString(file);
    var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files.Path);

    var model = new PostPicture
    {
        Name = name,
        Picture = file
    };

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);

    HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(json);

    httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    var response = client.PostAsync(Host, httpContent).Result;
    string res = "";
    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
    {
        // ... Read the string.
        Task<string> result = content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        res = result.Result;
    }
    var jsoss = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res);
    //var rootObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PostPicture>(File.ReadAllText(res));
    string f = jsoss.ToString();

    await DisplayAlert("Successfull", f, "OK");

}
```

Comment: `PostUserAsync` is `async`. You should not use `Task.Result` to get the results of other async methods, but `await` them!

Comment: Are you sure that the file is to be posted in the JSON? If so, did you compare the JSON sent via Postman and the one created from your App? How does your Postman request look like?

Comment: Furthermore I do not see where `files` is assigned. Is it?

Comment: https://ilclubdellesei.blog/2018/02/14/how-to-upload-images-to-an-asp-net-core-rest-service-with-xamarin-forms/